# Seemingly bizarre shapes required for multi-label class cGAN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am making a cGAN with a generator that takes in a shape `(86,)` label tensor and combines it with random noise of shape `(1000,)` to produce architectural CAD paths with shape `(6, 2532, 39, 5)`, and a standard cGAN discriminator. Here are my generator and discrimminator:

```py
def generator(latent_dim=1000, label_dim=86, output_data_shape=(6, 2532, 39, 5)):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=latent_dim * label_dim))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Dense(2))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Dense(np.prod(output_data_shape), activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Reshape(output_data_shape))

    model.summary()

    noise = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    label = Input(shape=(label_dim,))
    label_embedding = Embedding(label_dim, latent_dim, input_length=label_dim)(label)

    model_input = multiply([noise, label_embedding])
    model_input = Flatten()(model_input)
    img = model(model_input)

    return Model([noise, label_embedding], img)


def discriminator(latent_dim=1000, label_dim=86, output_data_shape=(6, 2532, 39, 5)):
    model = Sequential()

    # This is the max dims allowed or otherwise it'll run out of memory
    model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=np.prod(output_data_shape) * label_dim))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dense(128))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(128))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.summary()

    img = Input(shape=output_data_shape)
    label = Input(shape=(label_dim,))
    label_embedding = Embedding(label_dim, np.prod(output_data_shape))(label)
    flat_img = Flatten()(img)

    model_input = multiply([flat_img, label_embedding])
    model_input = Flatten()(model_input)

    validity = model(model_input)

    return Model([img, label], validity)
```

And for easier viewing, these are the respective shapes of the generator:

[image: Generator diagram]

And discrimminator:

[image: Discriminator diagram]

This model compiles, and the discriminator shapes make sense, but the generator shapes are bizarre. While I specifically set a label input shape of `Input(shape=(86,))`, why does the model state that the input shape for the labels is `Input(shape=(86, 1000))`?

Comment: Change `return Model([noise, label_embedding], img)` to `return Model([noise, label], img)` in your generator. Also ask yourself if you really need a latent space dimension of 1000.